# Flipper React-Navigation when trying to view routes throws error

Tags: react-native, react-native-debugger, fbflipper

I'm trying to use Flippers React-Native-Navigation plugin to view some routes and how they act in my app and for some reason the plugin throws this error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at RouteMap (C:\Users\user\.flipper\installed-plugins\flipper-plugin-react-navigation\1.3.11\dist\bundle.js:923:15)

    at ci (file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/Flipper-win/resources/app.asar/bundle.js:835:66373)

    at au (file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/Flipper-win/resources/app.asar/bundle.js:835:123572)

    at kl (file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/Flipper-win/resources/app.asar/bundle.js:835:118212)

    at jl (file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/Flipper-win/resources/app.asar/bundle.js:835:118140)

    at Zk (file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/Flipper-win/resources/app.asar/bundle.js:835:117993)

    at Vk (file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/Flipper-win/resources/app.asar/bundle.js:835:114998)

    at og (file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/Flipper-win/resources/app.asar/bundle.js:835:49169)

    at Rg (file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/Flipper-win/resources/app.asar/bundle.js:835:112099)

    at yi (file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/Flipper-win/resources/app.asar/bundle.js:835:71799)

    at C:\Users\user\.flipper\installed-plugins\flipper-plugin-react-navigation\1.3.11\dist\bundle.js:832:11
```

Has anyone came across this I'm having trouble finding any relatable issues.